# SQL DROP TABLE foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, database-table, drop-table

If I want to delete all the tables in my database like this, will it take care of the foreign key constraint? If not, how do I take care of that first?

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[Course]','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.[Course]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[Student]','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.[Student]
```

Comment: [Check this link](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-remove-drop-foreign-keys-in-sql.html)

Comment: Check this answer, it helped me ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5488670/2205144

Answer (score 390, accepted):

No, this will not drop your table if there are indeed foreign keys referencing it.

To get all foreign key relationships referencing your table, you could use this SQL (if you're on SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Student')
```

and if there are any, with this statement here, you could create SQL statements to actually drop those FK relations:

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE [' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + name + ']'
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Student')
```

Comment: Note: the generated table contains the statements to delete the individual constraints to be run in a different query. It worked wonders in my case since I needed to get rid of an useless table (for testing purposes) while maintaining the rest of the tables that had FK to it intact.

Comment: I had to use parent_object_id instead of referenced_object_id

Comment: An alternative to the SELECT statement for getting all referencing tables is: EXEC sp_fkeys 'Student';

Comment: small adjustment this query

    SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT  [name] '
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Student')

replace [name] with CONSTRAINT name

Comment: works good thanks. (I got an error because I needed to put foreign key name into [ ] . )

Comment: Great solution marc_s. Alternatively one could use (not as nice, but easy to execute): `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a,table_b,table_c,table_etc;  
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` 
In this way it doesn't matter in what order you use the tables in your query.

Comment: How to assign your last select as a variable and execute it?

Answer (score 61):

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (R2)  and newer, you can Right Click on the

> DB -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts

- Select the tables you want to DROP.
- Select "Save to new query window".
- Click on the Advanced button.
- Set Script DROP and CREATE to Script DROP.
- Set Script Foreign Keys to True.
- Click OK.
- Click Next -> Next -> Finish.
- View the script and then Execute.

Comment: still the same 'Could not drop object 'my_table' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: How this answer has 28 + rating is beyond me... still doesn't work mate

Comment: While it does generate the script - that script does not solve the problem, which is drop the table referenced by Foreign Key constraints.

Comment: SQL 2019, worked great, has foreign key constraints, went through them with no problem.

Comment: SSMS 18.12.1 Works a treat! Had heaps of FK constraints and it worked perfectly! Cheers.

Comment: I upvoted this thinking it sounded great. By the time I tried it, and relised it wasn't useful, I am no longer allowed to take my upvote back. There is no "Advanced button" or "Script Foreign Keys to True" option that I can see. I'm on SQL Server 12.

Comment: The "Advanced" button is on the "Set Scripting Options" tab to the right of "Save as Notebook" radio button. The UI is... not great. This worked for me, with SSMS 19.0.2 and SQL Server 16.0.1000.6 (Dev Edition).

Answer (score 33):

If you drop the "child" table first, the foreign key will be dropped as well. If you attempt to drop the "parent" table first, you will get an "Could not drop object 'a' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint." error.

Comment: True, but no solution. Child can have foreign keys to oher tables and/or you might not want to drop it in the first place.

Comment: True, and a solution if the goal is, as stated, "If I want to delete all the tables in my database..."

Comment: this is a much better answer than the accepted one, given that the questioner wants to "delete all the tables in my database"

Answer (score 25):

Here is another way to drop all tables correctly, using `sp_MSdropconstraints` procedure. The shortest code I could think of:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable "declare @name nvarchar(max); set @name = parsename('?', 1); exec sp_MSdropconstraints @name";
exec sp_MSforeachtable "drop table ?";
```

Comment: This answers the original question "If I want to delete all the tables in my database" really  with the help of this simple 2 lines. At least for my SQLServer 2019. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more generic version of what @mark_s posted, this helped me

```
SELECT 
'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(k.parent_object_id) +
'.[' + OBJECT_NAME(k.parent_object_id) + 
'] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + k.name
FROM sys.foreign_keys k
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('your table')
```

just plug your table name, and execute the result of it.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to drop my foreign key constraints by the above, but when I go to drop a table afterwards, it keeps saying "Could not drop the object because it still is being referenced by a Foreign Key constraint...any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

everything is much simpler. There is a configuration to turn off the check and turn it on.

For example, if you are using MySQL, then to turn it off, you must write `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

Then delete or clear the table, and re-enable the check `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

If it is SQL Server you must drop the constraint before you can drop the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do delete all the constraints followed by the tables themselves, using a concatenation trick involving `FOR XML PATH('')` which allows merging multiple input rows into a single output row.   Should work on anything SQL 2005 & later.

I've left the EXECUTE commands commented out for safety.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
;WITH fkeys AS (
    SELECT quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(o.name) tablename, quotename(fk.name) constraintname 
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    JOIN sys.objects o ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT '; ALTER TABLE ' + tablename + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + constraintname
FROM fkeys
FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

-- EXECUTE(@sql)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT '; DROP TABLE ' + quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

-- EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Comment: This doesn't work well because of not all FK will be dropped (only those where our tables is used as parent, where we should drop also constraint where our table was used as "referenced" ).

Comment: Roman, the original post is about deleting foreign key constraints.  My answer doesn't aim to cover anything beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete script to implement a solution:

```
create Procedure [dev].DeleteTablesFromSchema
(
    @schemaName varchar(500)
)
As 
begin
    declare @constraintSchemaName nvarchar(128), @constraintTableName nvarchar(128),  @constraintName nvarchar(128)
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    -- delete FK first
    declare cur1 cursor for
    select distinct 
    CASE WHEN t2.[object_id] is NOT NULL  THEN  s2.name ELSE s.name END as SchemaName,
    CASE WHEN t2.[object_id] is NOT NULL  THEN  t2.name ELSE t.name END as TableName,
    CASE WHEN t2.[object_id] is NOT NULL  THEN  OBJECT_NAME(d2.constraint_object_id) ELSE OBJECT_NAME(d.constraint_object_id) END as ConstraintName
    from sys.objects t 
        inner join sys.schemas s 
            on t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
        left join sys.foreign_key_columns d 
            on  d.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
        left join sys.foreign_key_columns d2 
            on  d2.referenced_object_id = t.[object_id]
        inner join sys.objects t2 
            on  d2.parent_object_id = t2.[object_id]
        inner join sys.schemas s2 
            on  t2.[schema_id] = s2.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.[type]='U' 
        AND t2.[type]='U'
        AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
        AND t2.is_ms_shipped = 0 
        AND s.Name=@schemaName
    open cur1
    fetch next from cur1 into @constraintSchemaName, @constraintTableName, @constraintName
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        set @sql ='ALTER TABLE ' + @constraintSchemaName + '.' + @constraintTableName+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+@constraintName+';'
        exec(@sql)
        fetch next from cur1 into @constraintSchemaName, @constraintTableName, @constraintName
    END
    close cur1
    deallocate cur1

    DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(128)
    declare cur2 cursor for
    select s.Name, p.Name
    from sys.objects p
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE p.[type]='U' and is_ms_shipped = 0 
    AND s.Name=@schemaName
    ORDER BY s.Name, p.Name
    open cur2

    fetch next from cur2 into @schemaName,@tableName
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @sql ='DROP TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName
        exec(@sql)
        fetch next from cur2 into @schemaName,@tableName
    end

    close cur2
    deallocate cur2

end
go
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Removing Referenced FOREIGN KEY Constraints
Assuming there is a parent and child table Relationship in SQL Server:

--First find the name of the Foreign Key Constraint:
  SELECT * 
  FROM sys.foreign_keys
  WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('States')

--Then Find foreign keys referencing to dbo.Parent(States) table:
   SELECT name AS 'Foreign Key Constraint Name', 
           OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS 'Child Table'
   FROM sys.foreign_keys 
   WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo' AND 
              OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo.State'

 -- Drop the foreign key constraint by its name 
   ALTER TABLE dbo.cities DROP CONSTRAINT FK__cities__state__6442E2C9;

 -- You can also use the following T-SQL script to automatically find 
 --and drop all foreign key constraints referencing to the specified parent 
 -- table:

 BEGIN

DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(300);

-- Cursor to generate ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT statements  
 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
 SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + 
 OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) +
                ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
 FROM sys.foreign_keys 
 WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo' AND 
            OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'states';

 OPEN cur;
 FETCH cur INTO @stmt;

 -- Drop each found foreign key constraint 
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    EXEC (@stmt);
    FETCH cur INTO @stmt;
  END

  CLOSE cur;
  DEALLOCATE cur;

  END
  GO

--Now you can drop the parent table:

 DROP TABLE states;
--# Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a **my**sql server  (**not MS**SQL) and if you don't mind loosing your tables, you can use a simple query to delete multiple tables at once:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a,table_b,table_c,table_etc;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

In this way it doesn't matter in what order you use the table in you query.

If anybody is going to say something about the fact that this is not a good solution if you have a database with many tables: I agree!

Comment: I get `Incorrect syntax near '='. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)`

Comment: @Matt Bit hard to guess at which '=' you get that error.

Comment: `foreign_key_checks` will not work on MSSQL server. I think that's a MySql specific variable.

Comment: @ooXei1sh No not on MSSQL. That is why I say at the start of my post: "If you are on a MYSQL server".

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server Manager you can drop foreign key constraints from the UI. If you want to delete the table `Diary` but the User table has a foreign key `DiaryId` pointing to the `Diary` table, you can expand (using the plus symbol) the `User` table and then expand the `Foreign Keys` section. Right click on the foreign key that points to the diary table then select `Delete`. You can then expand the `Columns` section, right click and delete the column `DiaryId` too. Then you can just run:

```
drop table Diary
```

---

I know your actual question is about deleting all tables, so this may not be a useful for that case. However, if you just want to delete a few tables this is useful I believe (the title does not explicitly mention deleting all tables).

Answer (score 0):

execute the below code to get the foreign key constraint name which blocks your drop. For example, I take the `roles` table.

```
      SELECT *
      FROM sys.foreign_keys
      WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('roles');

      SELECT name AS 'Foreign Key Constraint Name',
      OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
      AS 'Child Table' FROM sys.foreign_keys
      WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo'
      AND OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo.roles'
```

you will get the FK name something as below : `FK__Table1__roleId__1X1H55C1`

now run the below code to remove the FK reference got from above.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.users drop CONSTRAINT FK__Table1__roleId__1X1H55C1;
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Find all foreign key.. script them

```
SELECT *  FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Student')
```

and then delete foreign keys from child table.
now you can drop parent table .

if you want to recreate the parent table make sure to run the script you have created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This script will let you delete all Foreign Key Contrainsts using a string match on the Contraint name

```sql
    DECLARE @constraintMatchString nvarchar(max) = N'FK_<SOME-MATCH-STRING>%';
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

    ;WITH x (schemaAndTableName, constraintName) AS 
    (
      SELECT 
        schemaAndTableName = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)),
        constraintName = name
      FROM sys.foreign_keys
      where name like @constraintMatchString
      group by QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)), name
    )
    SELECT @sql += N'ALTER TABLE ' + schemaAndTableName + N' DROP CONSTRAINT [' +constraintName +N'];
    ' FROM x;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Just replace the `FK_<SOME-MATCH-STRING>%` value as needed (and note, the `%` is a wildcard match)

Answer (score -5):

If you want to `DROP` a table which has been referenced by other table using the foreign key use

`DROP TABLE *table_name* CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;`
I think it should work for you.

Comment: there is no `cascade constraints` in sql server

Answer (score -11):

> If I want to delete all the tables in
>   my database

Then it's a lot easier to drop the entire database:

```
DROP DATABASE WorkerPensions
```

Comment: Giving you a -1 for this as it is not a valid answer to the question, for two important reasons:

1) It deletes a lot more than tables!  Stored procedures, functions, UDTs, security, .NET assemblies, etc. all go away with a DROP DATABASE.

2) You may not be allowed to create databases, e.g. centrally-managed dev environment where databases are provisioned by IT and have additional requirements at create-time that you aren't aware of.

Comment: @WarrenRumak whilst your comment is valid as a disclaimer, I don't think the answer is the worst suggestion, given the op's opener (it's "their" database). Andomar should just update with a big warning that this would not leave you with an empty database so much as the database itself would cease to exist, so use with extreme caution.