# How to disable and enable all constraints on all tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

- I want to delete some duplicate data in one table.Here every table is related to some other table.So i want to disable all constraints on all tables.After deleting the duplicate data i want to enable the constraints*
  I tried so many solutions but no one working properly.Please help me out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972816/how-to-disable-constraints-for-all-the-tables-and-enable-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I did*
Step 1:first go to edit ->preferences->sql-editor
    In Query editor
disable the ‘safe updates...’

Step 2:close mysql workbench

Step 3:Open mysql workbench
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

Step 4:delete the records which are not deleting due to constraints previously

Step 5:SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Step 6:go to edit ->preferences->sql-editor
    In Query editor
enable the ‘safe updates...’

Step 7:Close and Open mysql workbench

It works for me