# How to disable and enable constraints on sql database schema for inserting data from dsv files?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I am trying to import data from a dsv file to a hsql database but for that I have to disable the constraints on the schema. There was a command like `Alter Schemaname` or similar, but i don't remember details.

Comment: [probably the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972816/how-to-disable-constraints-for-all-the-tables-and-enable-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE; // to disable REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY
```

Documentation link is [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#set_refint-section)

Comment: will this query work : ALTER SCHEMANAME SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;