# How can I drop a table if there is a foreign key constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[ExtraUserInformation];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExtraUserInformation] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [FullName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Link]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Verified] BIT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ExtraUserInformation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId])
);
```

However this is failing with a message saying:

```
Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Could not drop object 'dbo.UserProfile' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Could not drop object 'dbo.webpages_Roles' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 27
There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.
Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

How can I drop a table in these circumstances?

Comment: drop references first

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776079/sql-drop-table-foreign-key-constraint

This is a common SQL Server task

Comment: you have to DROP CONSTRAINS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL DROP TABLE foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776079/sql-drop-table-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: In case someone is using MS SQL Server Management Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71969142/7389293

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must drop the constraint before you can drop the table. Otherwise its rule violation that could break the databases Referential Integrity.

How to get foreign key relationships see this old question.
[SQL DROP TABLE foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776079/sql-drop-table-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 11):

1-firstly, drop the foreign key constraint after that drop the tables.

2-you can drop all foreign key via executing the following query:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000)=''
SELECT @SQL = 
@SQL + 'ALTER TABLE ' + s.name+'.'+t.name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(f.name) +'];' + CHAR(13)
FROM sys.Tables t
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas     s ON s.schema_id = f.schema_id

--EXEC (@SQL)

PRINT @SQL
```

if you execute the printed results @SQL, the foreign keys will be dropped.

Comment: This generates **all** DROP CONSTRAINT statements, not just the ones "we" care about.

Answer (score 6):

The Best Answer to dropping the table containing foreign constraints is :

- Step 1 : Drop the Primary key of the table.
- Step 2 : Now it will prompt whether to delete all the foreign references or not.
- Step 3 : Delete the table.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. all i wanted was to run script to update users table in the DB, and to test, I wanted to just copy the user table from live to dev copy... not have to copy the entire 5gb DB.

Answer (score 4):

To drop a table if there is a foreign key constraint in MySQL Server?

Run the sql query:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE table_name

Hope it helps!

Comment: The question is about Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: Although, this question was about SQL Server, I wanted to do the same thing in MySQL and this answer was what helped me.

Answer (score 4):

```
    --Find and drop the constraints

    DECLARE @dynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 

    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR
        SELECT dynamicSQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + name + ']'
        FROM sys.foreign_keys
        WHERE object_name(referenced_object_id)  in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')
    OPEN MY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @dynamicSQL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        PRINT @dynamicSQL
        EXEC (@dynamicSQL)

        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @dynamicSQL
    END
    CLOSE MY_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR


    -- Drop tables
    DROP 'table1'
    DROP 'table2'
    DROP 'table3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to drop the constraint before drop your table.

You can use those queries to find all FKs in your table and find the FKs in the tables in which your table is used.

```
Declare @SchemaName VarChar(200) = 'Your Schema name'
Declare @TableName VarChar(200) = 'Your Table Name'

-- Find FK in This table.
SELECT 
    ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = 
OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + FK.name + ']'
+ ''') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + 
OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ']' + ''')) ' +

    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name
    , S.name , O.name, OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS FK
INNER JOIN Sys.objects As O 
  ON (O.object_id = FK.parent_object_id )
INNER JOIN SYS.schemas AS S 
  ON (O.schema_id = S.schema_id)  
WHERE 
      O.name = @TableName
      And S.name = @SchemaName


-- Find the FKs in the tables in which this table is used
  SELECT 
    ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id =   
      OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + FK.name + ']'
  + ''') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + 
 OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ']' + ''')) ' +

    ' ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name
    , S.name , O.name, OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS FK
INNER JOIN Sys.objects As O 
  ON (O.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id )
INNER JOIN SYS.schemas AS S 
  ON (O.schema_id = S.schema_id)  
WHERE 
      O.name = @TableName
      And S.name = @SchemaName
```

Comment: Excelent procedure !!

Comment: This is insane. I have a table which has a foreign key constraint on itself (its own column references another table). SQL Server really should have the smarts to just drop that contraint before it drops the table when I issue a command to drop the table. Unfathomable that it can't handle that.

Answer (score 1):

[BhupeshC and murat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482464/4489806) , this is what I was looking for. However @SQL varchar(4000) wasn't big enough. So, small change

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 

select 'ALTER TABLE ['+s.name+'].['+t.name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(f.name) +'];' FROM sys.Tables t INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = f.schema_id

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @cmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- EXEC (@cmd)
    PRINT @cmd
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @cmd
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Re removing constraints and dropping the tables, this script can get all constraints for a selected list of tables and then drop the constraints and then delete the tables.

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @deleteCurser CURSOR
DECLARE @deleteTableCurser CURSOR



declare @SelectedTables table ([name] sysname, [object_id] int)
Insert into @SelectedTables ([name], [object_id])
SELECT t.name, t.object_id 
FROM sys.Tables t
where t.name in
-- Change Name of tables here
('table1','table2','table100')



SET @deleteTableCurser = CURSOR FOR
SELECT strSQL = 
'ALTER TABLE ' + s.name+'.'+t.name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(f.name) +'];'
FROM @SelectedTables t
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas     s ON s.schema_id = f.schema_id


OPEN @deleteTableCurser
FETCH Next 
FROM @deleteTableCurser INTO @strSQL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print(@strSQL)
    EXEC (@strSQL)
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @deleteTableCurser INTO @strSQL
END

CLOSE @deleteTableCurser
DEALLOCATE @deleteTableCurser


SET @deleteCurser = CURSOR FOR
SELECT strSQL = 'DROP TABLE ['+ t.name+ '];'
FROM @SelectedTables t

OPEN @deleteCurser
FETCH Next 
FROM @deleteCurser INTO @strSQL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print(@strSQL)
    EXEC (@strSQL)
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @deleteCurser INTO @strSQL
END


CLOSE @deleteCurser
DEALLOCATE @deleteCurser
```

Answer (score -3):

Type this .... `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`
delete your table then type `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

[MySQL – Temporarily disable Foreign Key Checks or Constraints](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/)