# FK_Supplier_UserType_UserTypeId error

Tags: sql, database, powershell

I am trying to update-database by using powershell. but I am getting this error:

> "FK_Supplier_UserType_UserTypeId"

which I already deleted the table (UserType)

Anyone can help?

I searched "usertypeId" all database and codes but I can't find it...What is the issue here and what am I supposed to to?

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not posted the whole error message it is saying that another table references `UserTypeId` of `UserType` table.

Before to drop a table, you must ensure there isn't any reference or dependency to this table.

Have a look at this question: [How can I drop a table if there is a foreign key constraint in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15107238/3270427)

Comment: Thanks for comments...I already dropped the table(UserType) at the database level by mistake...that's why I am getting this message..what should I do for this?

Comment: You should drop foreign key constraint. This question shows how to find FK dependencies. https://stackoverflow.com/q/925738/3270427