# Foreign Keys left after table deletion?

Tags: sql, ssms

So here's an interesting one for you... I am working on copying one entire database `(db1)` and structure over from one database to another `(db2)`, and before doing so I decided to try and drop all tables from the db2.  I did the usual `sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAING ALL'` and then `sp_msforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'` and much to my dismay, it deleted all save for maybe 6 tables.  These tables seemed to still have foreign key references to them.  I did a search and found this [SQL DROP TABLE foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776079/sql-drop-table-foreign-key-constraint) which showed me how to find and then try to delete those foreign key references.

This is the interesting part: upon attempting to delete them using that information, I have been told that ssms cannot find the object because it does not exist or I do not have permission.  The foreign key reference is coming from a table that I have previously deleted.

How is that possible?  And how on earth do I progress from here?

Comment: Another minor update, upon querying Sys.Objects for objects LIKE table_blah, I have received a list which has several default constraint objects, foreign key constraint objects, a primary key constraint object, and still the table itself despite no longer being visible in the tree structure and despite my not being able to view it using a select statement

Comment: Consider this issue closed!

I just went ahead and took the easy route of deleting db1 and restoring a copy of db2 in place of db1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by *them* in "upon attempting to delete them".  If you were trying to delete the foreign key from the system tables, that would definitely be a mistake.

My guess is you can just drop those last 6 tables now.

Suppose we have two tables A and B

```
create table A (a int) 
create table B(b int, foreign key (b) references (A.a))
```

and we try to drop the tables.  `drop table A` will fail, because B references it with a declared foreign key.  But we can freely `drop table B`, because A doesn't care if it's no longer being referenced.

So after the first pass, one `DROP` failed and one succeeded, leaving one table, now with no FK references.  Try again and, voila!, `drop table A` now works.

Comment: The _them_ refers to the foreign keys that were the result of the query that I found in the link I posted up there.

'ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT FK_whatever1'

Obviously these aren't the real names... anyway, I'll try and explain better.  That statement up there was the result of the query that I found in the link.  The issue here is that FK_whatever1 still exists but table1 does not so now I get the following error upon trying to run that statement:

"Cannot find the object table1 because it does not exist or you do not have permission".

Table1 is deleted, how does that FK exist?